# Create automatic folder in NAS

Tags: script, qnap

In my qnap NAS, I want to create a folder automatically inside other folder on creation. For example, a user make the folder Antoine and automatically the qnap created _tmp inside the Antoine folder. But this, is created only if folder is making on second level of path. (RootFolder/FolderA/Antoine)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why? Also: Do you want to create the directories _only_ in the second level or in the second level _and_ below?

Comment: To simplify the life of my users and learn:) No only in second level. Inside the folder Antoine in my exemple. RootFolder/FolderA/Antoine/_tmp Or RootFolder/FolderB/Benoit/_tmp

Comment: Which tool ultimately creates the directory?

Comment: I don't know ! I just want to find a solution :) If that is tool or script for me is the same at this moment.